# Sum of values accessed through numpy memmap is wrong

Tags: python, numpy, memory

I have a large (9.3 GB) `.npy` file containing a `uint8` values in an (67000, 9, 128, 128) ndarray. I created it using `np.save()` and when loading it using `x = np.memmap('file.npy', "uint8", shape=(67000, 9, 128, 128), mode="r")`, `np.sum(x[0,0,:,0])` returns 13783. The "problem" is that when I try loading it with `np.load("file.npy")` and run the same function, I get the sum to 13768.

Since `np.load()` loads the whole file in memory, I'd assume that the sum computed on its ndarray is correct, while the one returned by the ndarray loaded with memmap is wrong, but why are they different ? If it was a reading error the sum should be really off, so why is it off by only 15 ??!

I have no clue why that is the case. This won't affect my computation *per say* but it could be significant for other tasks.

Comment: Can you reproduce the problem with a smaller array, so that it's small enough to print the mapped version and the loaded version?

Comment: npy-files have a header, but `memmap` maps raw bytes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`numpy.memmap` is for treating *raw data* in a file as a numpy array.  Your filename is `'file.npy'`, so that is not "raw" data.  It is a NPY file, which has a header containing meta-information about the array stored in it.

To memory-map a NPY file, use the `mmap_mode` argument of `numpy.load()`.

Comment: Thanks, that works well ! I now use `viddata = np.load(viddata_path, mmap_mode="r+")` . However, later on I need to convert my ndarray to `float32` dtype but I run into a MemoryError which is what I was trying to avoid in the first place. Any tips ?

Comment: Perhaps work in batches?  Really, a question about memory management is too broad to be handled in stackoverflow comments.  If you can't figure something out, ask another SO question.

Comment: Okay, thank you, for people reading this post, I found [Dask](https://dask.pydata.org/en/latest/) which helps handle up to 100 Go arrays and is compatible with numpy ndarrays, pandas DataFrame and scikit-learn.